# jquery blinking text and div reload

Tags: jquery

I have a div that refreshes every 30 seconds and I also have text that blinks if it's new content (checked by a cookie).

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#reload').load('/page.php #reload'), function() {}
}, 30000);

// check if atis cookie exits
var Key = $("#key").data('key');
if ($.cookie('check_'+Key) == null) {
  $('.blink_'+Key).each(function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      setInterval(function() {
          if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
              elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
          } else {
              elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
          }    
      }, 500);
  });
}
```

The blinking works perfectly...until the div refreshes. Once the div refreshes, the blinking stops. I've tried adding the blinking code inside the refresh function, but no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you move your blinking code to success handle in your load function?

Comment: I don't think there is a success handle for the load function ...if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The second parameter to your .load function is the success handler. The one which you have kept empty

Comment: I put it in the curly brackets in the function but the blinking still ceases after the 30 second refresh.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a some syntax error in the code you provided. Your load function should have two arguments like `$('#reload').load('/page.php #reload', function(){})`
Try the following code:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('#reload').load('/page.php #reload', blinkText)
}, 30000);

function blinkText() {
    // check if atis cookie exits
    var Key = $("#key").data('key');
    if ($.cookie('check_' + Key) == null) {
        $('.blink_' + Key).each(function () {
            var elem = $(this);
            setInterval(function () {
                if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
                    elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
                } else {
                    elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting these codes inside a function so it looks like this:

```
function checkForNewContent() {
// check if atis cookie exits
var Key = $("#key").data('key');
if ($.cookie('check_'+Key) == null) {
  $('.blink_'+Key).each(function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      setInterval(function() {
          if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
              elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
          } else {
              elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
          }    
      }, 500);
  });
}
}
```

and then add the newly added function in the function callback of your first lines of codes so it looks like this..

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#reload').load('/page.php #reload'), function() { checkForNewContent(); }
}, 30000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still stops flashing.